# Open File after Downloading Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm creating an App store on Android Studio.
I use a web View where the download button is for the apks, and I would like to open the file after downloading it.
I'm getting the message that its downloading but I can't find the file on my phone

this is my java code:

```
    

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("https://web.redstoneresort.de/appstore.html");
        webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        
    }
```

Comment: Wel it should be here: request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,

Comment: Do you get a notification when download done?

Comment: @blackapps no i didnt get a notification after the download

Comment: Why didnt you tell? You asked for one. Only if you get a notification download completed you could stand up and look for the file.