# File upload button not working in webview android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

hello friends i just followed a tutorial on how to convert my website to an app using webview in android studio
i tested the app and find out that upload image button is not working
this is the code that i copied from the tutorial
AndriodManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.krilidz">
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.KriliDZ">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.krilidz;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.krilidz.com/ar/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

im sorry if this is a silly question it's my first time doing something like this, thank you

Comment: I see no upload image button.

Comment: the upload image button is on the website not on this code as i followed up in the tutorial ,he did this to show a website like it is on the app, i dont know if there some permission to allow image uploads or somthing so it can work, it works fine on the website @blackapps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687570/open-file-after-downloading-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment123180551_69687570